# Use of 'optimize' proclamation

Tags: performance, lisp, common-lisp

To enhance efficiency of my Lisp program, I want to insert this line into my code:

```
(optimize (speed 3) (safety 0) (debug 0) (space 0))
```

Currently I think I should put it at the top of each file. Is it a good idea or should I insert this line in one specific place? (I use ASDF for system definition.)

Another part of my question: is `(safety 0)` safe? Few of my functions use explicit declarations of variable types, what will happen to the others? Should I omit `(safety 0)` to avoid problems that might occur due to missing type-checking?

Comment: You might look at the source of [CL-PPCRE](http://weitz.de/cl-ppcre/) and look at how Edi Weitz handles optimization declarations.  I seem to recall it being an interesting approach.

Comment: @Joshua, Thank you! This Lisp code is a good example for me. It also uses ASDF and now I see some little details that I should adopt. Optimization declarations are indeed smart :-) A find!

Comment: I'm glad it was useful!  To be honest, I don't remember quite what the approach was there, just that when I saw it my reaction was along the lines of "huh?  what is this for? … ? … OOOO… nice!"

Comment: @Joshua, He defines a variable, which holds desired settings and then just puts `(declare #.*standard-optimize-settings*)` where's needed. I think I will use `#.` with functions like `constantly` and `complement` now, to get their results at compile time, not at run-time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would avoid setting compilation policies globally, since ["as with other defining macros, it is unspecified whether or not the compile-time side-effects of a declaim persist after the file has been compiled"](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_declai.htm#declaim). If you really want to use a global policy per file, you can use the [`locally` special form](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_locall.htm) at top-level (subforms of a top-level `locally` remain top-level forms)

```
(locally (declare (optimize speed #| ... whatever ... |#))

   (defun compute-foo (x) 
     (1+ x))

   (defun compute-bar (y) 
     (* (compute-foo y) y)))
```

instead of

```
(declaim (optimize speed #| ... whatever ... |#))
...
```

or even

```
(proclaim '(optimize speed #| ... whatever ... |#))
```

I tend to use declarations sparingly, usually only local within a function, i.e.,

```
(defun compute-foo (x)
   (declare (fixnum x))
   (1+ x))
```

Many modern Lisp compilers (like SBCL) have become pretty good at figuring types out. Further, I'd never use `(safety 0)` globally, since it may be dangerous, in particular during development, when things haven't really settled down and mistakes are common.

Comment: Does it make sense to use `optimize` declarations inside of function `declaim`ed `inline`?

Comment: Frankly, I don't know. The standard doesn't really define, what the compiler is supposed to do under a given optimisation policy. You should read the documentation of your Lisp implementation, if you really bother.